# Duplicación de complementos: ¿qué exactamente es un 'pronombre personal'?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, clíticos

Voy revisando la duplicación de complementos y he encontrado una explicación buena en el DPD.  Pero no entiendo exactamente qué se quiere decir [aquí](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos#51):

> 5.1. Si el complemento tónico es también un pronombre personal, la coaparición del pronombre átono es obligatoria, tanto si el
> complemento es directo como indirecto: Me castigaron a mí; A ti te
> dieron el premio (no *Castigaron a mí; *A ti dieron el premio). Aunque
> son posibles, en estos casos, oraciones idénticas sin el complemento
> tónico (Me castigaron; Te dieron el premio), existen diferencias
> expresivas de importancia entre ambas posibilidades: la presencia del
> complemento tónico denota un propósito de contraste o discriminación,
> ausente de la oración en la que solo aparece el pronombre átono; así,
> en Me castigaron a mí, frente a Me castigaron, se subraya el hecho de
> que ha sido solo a mí, y no a otros igualmente merecedores de ello o
> más culpables que yo, a quien se ha castigado.

En este contexto, ¿cuáles son los pronombres personales? O dicho de otra manera: ¿cuáles no lo son? ¿No son todos los pronombres --me, te, le, etc-- pronombres personales?  Es decir, estoy intentando entender cuando es obligatorio la duplicación de complementos, y si sigo lo que se dice más arriba, haciéndolo siempre y cuando haya un pronombre personal, ¿cuáles son los pronombres que no exigen la duplicación?  ¿O he malentendido lo que quiere decir la entrada del DPD?

Comment: *me, te, le* etc son pronombres personales **átonos**, pero al principio, habla de complementos **tónicos**, que corresponderían entonces a pronombres personales **tónicos** (es decir, *yo, tú, vos, él, ella, ello, usted, nosotros, nosotras, vosotros, vosotras, ellos, ellas, ustedes*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El punto 5.1. hace referencia a la duplicación obligatoria del objeto o complemento, directo o indirecto, cuando el complemento "de base" es un pronombre personal tónico:

- (preposición "a") + mí / ti / usted / vos / él / ella / nosotros / nosotras / vosotros / vosotras / ustedes / ellos / ellas

Cuando el complemento es un pronombre personal tónico, se debe duplicar con un pronombre personal átono:

- me / te / se / le / la / lo / nos / os / les / las / los

Ejemplos:

- **Me** castigaron a **mí** ("me" es pronombre personal átono, "mí" es pronombre personal tónico)
- A **ti** **te** dieron el premio ("ti" es pronombre personal tónico, "te" es pronombre personal átono)
- **Le** trajeron el regalo a **ella** ("le" es pronombre personal átono, "ella" es pronombre personal tónico)
- **Nos** eligieron a **nosotros** ("nos" es pronombre personal átono, "nosotros" es pronombre personal tónico)

Lo que dice el punto del DPD en cuestión es que, cuando aparecen "a mí", "a ti", "a ella", "a nosotros" (complementos con pronombres personales tónicos) en los ejemplos precedentes, DEBEN usarse además los pronombres personales átonos "me", "te", "le", "nos".

Los pronombres, también personales, "yo" y "tú" son siempre sujeto y NO admiten su uso como complementos directos o indirectos (*a yo, *a tú).